# What is the earliest instance of the use of term "blaster" in sci-fi to denote energy-based weapon?

Tags: star-wars, weapon, history-of

> “Hokey religions and ancient weapons are no match for a good blaster at your side, kid.” - Han Solo, naturally.

So, by the time Star Wars was released, blaster was an established science-fiction term for an energy-based weapon (aka ray gun). But what was the first known usage of the term in that context?

Comment: There might not be a direct connection, but a *blaster* was one who detonated rocks in the mining industry, and the term dates back to 1776. A 1921 [*Engineering and Mining Journal*](http://home.us.archive.org/stream/emjengineeringmi111newy#page/44/mode/1up) (page 44, right-hand column) reports of a new detonating device: 'This "Davis No. 1 Blaster" is so small that it fits the average hand, but has power to fire five 30-ft. copper-wire electric caps connected in series.'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Jeff Prucher's *[Brave New Words: The Oxford Dictionary of Science Fiction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195387066)* gives a first use of 1925.

[image: blaster citation]

I heartily recommend *Brave New Words* to anybody interested in SF history or language.

Comment: Strange that the earliest quote in the full *Oxford English Dictionary* is from Asimov's 1950 *Pebble in the Sky*.

Answer (score 8):

I think I remember the early serial versions of Buck Rogers and Flash Gordon using the term, but even if they didn't, here's a reference to the term being used as early as 1925 in *When the Green Star Waned* by Nictzin Dyalhis.  I'm still looking for references to weapons in the early serials or comics that use the term "blaster."

Comment: I chose the other Dyalhis answer as accepted due to an actual citation, but this was a great answer as well! +1

Answer (score 7):

I imagine this is one of those questions that it will be hard to find a definitive answer. However, a quick search on google books produced this from Astounding science fiction, July 1939 (John W. Campbell, editor).

[image: text]

Answer (score 4):

EE Doc Smith mentions blasters in the Lensman series.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lensman#Weapons), there is the *DeLameter* in later books, *Lewiston* in "First Lensman". Chronologically, it would be "Galactic Patrol" 1937

Comment: Is there evidence that blasters are mentioned in the early Lensman series books?

Comment: @DVK: Short of reading the book and giving page numbers, I don't know. I *know* blasters are mentioned but it has been years since I've read them so resorted to Wikipedia. I hadn't realised that mathematical proof was needed...

Comment: my concern is that the series spans a LONG time (at least 1935s to 1950s), and while **some** books in a series had blasters (as Wikipedia says), the issue is whether it was the books which preceeded, say, July 1939). Since I'm looking for the *earliest*, that is kind of an important point

Comment: *Chronologically, it would be "Galactic Patrol" 1937* This introduces Kimball Kinnison.

Comment: Since I haven't gone through the book myself, I can't be sure, but [Google Books, says nope to Galactic Patrol](http://books.google.com/books?ei=1tKiTqaGIKXl0QHiqr2EBQ&ct=result&id=CnVWAAAAYAAJ&dq=galactic+patrol&q=blaster#search_anchor).

Comment: @Sam: It mentioned DeLameter as a hand projector though http://books.google.com/books?ei=1tKiTqaGIKXl0QHiqr2EBQ&ct=result&id=CnVWAAAAYAAJ&dq=galactic+patrol&q=delameter#search_anchor

Comment: Triplanetary (first book in the lensman series) has 6 mentions of blaster in the second chapter 'Fall of Atlantis. It specifically mentions blasters 'flaming'. Serialised from September 1937.

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to answer my own question, I have found these 2 relatively early mentions (interestingly, from same year), by following a list in Wikipedia's "ray gun" entry:

Book: Asimov's "[Lucky Starr and the Big Sun of Mercury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Starr_and_the_Big_Sun_of_Mercury)" (written in 1955, published 1956)

Movie: "[Forbidden Planet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_Planet)" (1956 as well)

However, I doubt that it's the earliest use ever, given "[SF Glossary](http://catb.org/~esr/sf-words/glossary.html#blaster)"'s mention:

> [first use unknown, goes back at least to 1930s]

Comment: Asimov used blasters earlier, in *Foundation*. *Foundation* provided quite a bit of inspiration for *Star Wars*, possibly including the term *blaster*. However, as others have noted, Asimov didn't invent that term.

Comment: @Gilles - I knew about Fundation, but for some reason was so 100% sure it was post-1950s that didn't even bother checking.